# Insert column into table while also shifting all adjacent cells VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in my excel sheet with a changing number of rows. On occasion a new column may need to be added to the table at the right.

I have accomplished this in VBA using
`tbl.ListColumns.Add().Name = temp`
where temp is the header name of the new column I am creating.

Now, the issue is, to the right of the table (not a part of the table), I have a column of populated cells. When I add a new column to the table, only the cells directly adjacent to the table shift to the right. Everything else in the adjacent column stays in its original position.

Is there a way to programmatically insert a new column into the right side table while also shifting the contents of the entire column adjacent to the table as well?

I have tried using `Columns(x).Insert shift:=xlShiftRight` but unless I'm using it wrong it only adds a new column to the sheet and I still have to add a new column to the table which causes the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ListColumns.Add()`, you can simply write something into a cell that is next to the table. When the column is empty (to be precise, only the cells next to the table need to be empty), Excel will automatically create a new column for the table. However, no shifting is done and the structure of the remaining sheet stays intact.

Now if I understand you correctly, there is already data next to the table, so you will need to insert a new (Excel-)column first.

The following routine will do exactly that: Search the first cell next to the table, insert a column and write something into the header row of that column.

```
Sub CreateNewTableColumn(table As ListObject, caption As String)
    Dim cell As Range
    ' Set Cell to first cell next to the table
    Set cell = table.ListColumns(table.ListColumns.Count).Range.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1)
    ' Add an column to the sheet at that position.
    cell.EntireColumn.Insert xlToRight
    ' As adding a column will move the cell reference, to back one column
    Set cell = cell.Offset(0, -1)
    ' Just write the Caption, this will automatically create a new column
    cell.Value = caption
End Sub
```

Assuming that `tbl` holds a reference to your table and `temp` holds the caption for the new column, you can call it with

```
CreateNewTableColumn tbl, temp
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me thank you! I wasn't aware that Excel would automatically create a new column for the table so this helps a lot